# Как сверстать такой балун для гугл карты?

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api

Есть такой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такой балун для гугл карты?

Answer (score 3):

```css
#map, html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  margin-left: -90px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.img img {
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

div.gm-style-iw-d,div.gm-style-iw {
  width:300px;
  height:66px;
  overflow:visible !important;
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

function initMap() {
  var kindzadza = {lat: 36.363, lng: 41.044};
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: kindzadza
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: `<div class="img"><img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/EvergreenBothDingo-small.gif"></div>
             Я скажу всем, до чего довёл планету<br>этот фигляр ПЖ! Пацаки чатланам на голову сели! Кю!`
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: kindzadza,
    map: map,
    title: 'kindzadza'
  });
  
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
```

Comment: Так не подходит. Нужно сделать именно балун на карте google, а не просто сверстать элемент. Это Google API.

Comment: @Denis изменил ответ